# order by one column, But put a specific content at the end

Tags: mysql

I have multiple columns. Two of them are:

Group (numeric, not unique)
Name (string, not unique)

I would need to order by Group descending, BUT, if the value "Name" equals "Empty" i should be displayed at the end of the Group...

```
Group    Name

1020    test1
1020    test2
1020    test3
1020    EMPTY  <-- end of Group 1020
1020    EMPTY  <-- end of Group 1020
3040    test6
3040    test7
3540    test8
3540    EMPTY  <-- end of Group 3540
15060   test9
15060   EMPTY  <-- end of Group 15060
```

How can this be done with a mysql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, expressions like `Name = 'EMPTY'` have the value `1` if true and `0` if false.

So you can use

```
          ORDER BY Group, Name = 'EMPTY', Name
```

to get all the not-EMPTY values first, then all the EMPTY ones.