# MySQL order by launch date within 3 months from now first, then launch date desc

Tags: mysql, date

I have got a table like the following. The select order needs to show closest launch date from now first(it is more urgent), then launch date desc. Say current date is 17-11-2017

**tblProduct**

```html
01-02-2016
09-05-2015
03-11-2017
30-11-2017
02-01-2018
09-06-2018
```

The output order should be

```html
30-11-2017
02-01-2018
09-06-2018
03-11-2017
09-05-2015
01-02-2016
```

The top 2 are within 3 months from now, so are shown first(between the 2 results, 30-11-2017 is closer from now so shown first).

What's the mysql query?

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate question. Still, this may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47339330/order-by-one-column-but-put-a-specific-content-at-the-end/47339544#47339544

Comment: your output should most likely have the last 2 entries swaped since 2015 < 2016

Comment: You’re storing dates using a date data type, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure not the most elegant way, but this could help you

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a6eca/1

```
SELECT *, IF(mydate BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD( NOW() , INTERVAL +3 MONTH) , 1, 0) as `dateInRange`
FROM `demo`
ORDER BY  `dateInRange` DESC,
     CASE WHEN `dateInRange` = 1 THEN `mydate` END ASC,
     CASE WHEN `dateInRange` = 0 THEN `mydate` END DESC
```

What this does is adds another column `dateInRange` to the selection (and sets it to 1 if date is between now and 3 monts from now.

Then in the order by part we first sort by this column (making sure all the dates that are in the 3 months range are on the top), and when this column is equal to 0, then we sort by the actual date ascending. If this column is 0 we sort by dates descending.
This code does what you would like, but there must be a more elegant way to go about this.